# Categorising User Theme Settings

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Shopify Liquid, how can I categorise theme settings in the schema so that all settings aren't bundled together? I would like for sub-headings, for example, "Logo Settings", "Top Block Settings", etc.

Below is an example of where I would like a category header to appear:

https://monosnap.com/direct/2fzPaPpK1qO7cYmpvLU19Ij59BZqCI

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `header` field or the `paragraph` field.

They are described in the Shopify documentation.

Refer to:

https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema#header-setting-type
https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema#paragraph